# Python function to make a list of numbers from user input

Tags: python, input, numbers, output, negative-number

I am to write code so that when I run the program, user input can write a couple of numbers and return the value of those numbers negated. Example, user calls the function with this:

```
neg([1, 2, -3, 54, -9])
```

And that will result in this output:

```
[-1,  -2,  3,  -54,  9]
```

I'm having trouble finding the right coding to solve this issue. I'm grateful for all help.

Comment: `neg = lambda l: map(0x0.__sub__, l)`

Comment: Serious answer: `def neg(l): return [-x for x in l]`

Comment: @mu無,  in response to your is mathematics 101 is -0 the opposite of 0?

Answer (score 1):

You can multiple the values of each item by `-1` to get the negative.

```
>>> mylist = [-1,2,-3,-4.6,0]
>>> neg_list = [-x for x in mylist]
>>> neg_list
[1, -2, 3, 4.6, 0]
```

You can see that this works for both positive and negative values within the list. It keeps `0` at `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1, 2, -3, 54, -9]

def neg(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] *= -1
    return lst

print neg(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the "inverse" of each item in the list, `map` will do just that for you:

```
In [1]: map(lambda item: -item, [1, 2, -3, 54, -9])
Out[1]: [-1, -2, 3, -54, 9]
```